# Node.js Task Creation within Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, task

Can I spawn tasks to run a function in parallel while returning values when each task has found it rather than when all are done? If so, what would I need to spawn the tasks & return once complete?

Example function I want to be running in parallel:

```
function example(){
    do{
        axios.get(url).then(result => {
            if(result.data == "success"){
                console.log(result.data)
                return i = 1;
            }
            else{i = 0;}
        }
    }
    while (i < 1);
}
```

I am not sure where to begin to be quite honest. I have watched Youtube videos on clusters, using promise based array maps etc. Looking for more clarity